# Dynamically change color form light to dark

Tags: javascript

I have a function that currently changes a series of div from dark to lighter, but I want to reverse it so it goes from light to dark.

It would be great if someone could help me. Thanks

```
function color(r,g,b){
 return 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
}

for (var i=-10; i < $('#lazyload:eq(0) .scroll-section').length/2 ; i++) {
     var r = 198;
     var g = 198;
     var b = 198;
    $('#lazyload:eq(0) .scroll-section:eq('+(i+10)+')').css('background' , color(r+(i*10),g+(i*10),b+(i*10)) );
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rn3yfp9o/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function color(r,g,b){  
  return 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
}
         
for (var i=0; i < $('#lazyload:eq(0) .scroll-section').length ; i++) {
  var r = 255;
  var g = 255;
  var b = 255;
  $('#lazyload:eq(0) .scroll-section:eq('+i+')').css('background' , color(r-(i*10),g-(i*10),b-(i*10)) );
};
```

```css
#lazyload{
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.scroll-section{
  width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lazyload">
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
      <div class="scroll-section"></div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Juste change `+` with `-` :

```
color(r-(i*10),g-(i*10),b-(i*10)) 
-------^--------^--------^
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rn3yfp9o/4/

Answer (score 0):

`(i + 10)` => loop iterates from start to end. to reverse the order, use `.scroll-section` length as `len - (i + 10)`.

```
$('#lazyload:eq(0) .scroll-section:eq('+(len - i - 10)+')').css('background' , color(r+(i*10),g+(i*10),b+(i*10)) );
```

check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rn3yfp9o/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using it as:

```
function color(r,g,b){
  return 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
 }

for (var i=$('#lazyload:eq(0) .scroll-section').length/2; i >=-10  ; i--) {
       var r = 198;
       var g = 198;
       var b = 198;
  $('#lazyload:eq(0) .scroll-section:eq('+(i-10)+')').css('background' , color(r-(i*10),g-(i*10),b-(i*10)) );
 };
```